# Vagrant-winrm not recognized when running kitchen list

Tags: vagrant, test-kitchen, vagrant-windows, vagrant-plugin

I have a very simple serverspec test that I'm trying to run for platform `windows-2012r2`. When I run `kitchen list` I get the following:

```
exception: "#<Kitchen::UserError: WinRM Transport requires the vagrant-winrm Vagra
  plugin to properly communicate with this Vagrant VM. Please install this plugin
  with: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winrm' and try again.>"
message: 'WinRM Transport requires the vagrant-winrm Vagrant plugin to properly
  communicate with this Vagrant VM. Please install this plugin with: `vagrant
  plugin install vagrant-winrm'' and try again.'
```

However, when I run `vagrant plugin list` I get the following:

```
vagrant-scp (0.5.7)
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
vagrant-winrm (0.7.0)
```

Any ideas why kitchen isn't recognizing winrm?

Comment: can you add `config.vm.communicator = "winrm"` in your Vagrantfile if its not set already

Comment: I added it but get the same result.